# Issues with low pass filter using TarsosDSP for Android

Tags: android, signal-processing, lowpass-filter, tarsosdsp

I have a simple code for processing a float buffer with a lowpass filter.
Here's the function:

```
    public static float[] lowPass(float[] buffer, float frequnecy) {

    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 16, 1, true, false);
    AudioEvent audioEvent = new AudioEvent(audioFormat, 1024);
    audioEvent.setFloatBuffer(buffer);

    LowPassFS lowPassFilter = new LowPassFS(frequnecy, DSP.SAMPLE_RATE);
    lowPassFilter.process(audioEvent);

    return audioEvent.getFloatBuffer();
}
```

The result is that the buffer isn't processed at all and returned as is. I can't find a related working example anywhere tough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `getFloatBuffer()` with `getByteBuffer()`, it may be that the float buffer holds the input value, but I have made a low pass filter successfully (it doesn't work too well above cut off of 300Hz though) and `getByteBuffer()` definitely gives the filtered values.